# Merge two arraylists

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview

Please help

I have two string arraylists, one with first names, one with last names.

The FirstNameList has values such as:

- Bob
- Greg
- Amy

and the LastNameList has values such as:

- Smith
- Jones
- Brown

---

I know how to make a 3rd arraylist which 'appends' one arraylist after another in a listview, so I get:

- Bob
- Greg
- Amy
- Smith
- Jones
- Brown

What I want to do is make a third arraylist that 'integrates' them into single rows in a listview so I get:

- Bob Smith
- Greg Jones
- Amy Brown

How do I do this? Can you give me a code example?

Comment: You must have tried something?

Comment: I tried iterating through each but couldnt get the syntax right.

Comment: I think this approach not healty. Because for every name and surname you must have same arrayList size then they must be in correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the lists are the same size...

```
for(int i=0;i<firstNames.size();i++)
    fullNames.add(firstNames.get(i) + " " + lastNames.get(i));
```

I won't go into other improvements much, but you really should consider a `People` object, or *something* to avoid this. It relies completely on the lists being the same size, and being in the right order.

Comment: Thank you I will look at an object as an option